# Excel #Name Error keeps popping up each time spreadsheet is opened

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a Excel Workbook in which I have created an analysis using Datatables. For some reason each time I open the workbook, the formulas that reference the Datatable turn into #Name erorrs.

The first time I opened it, I thought I had simply made a typo and needed to reenter the formula. I did that and saved the file. On opening it two minutes later.... same error!

The error is only for two referenced columns in the datatable. Other columns from the same table reference fine, without error!

Here a sample of what the error looks like:

`=SUMIFS(tblDB #REF!,tblDB[AWGW 2012],$B$3,tblDB[NWGW 2012],$B13)`

The file (saved as an .xlsm) contains the following, none of which are used or touched by the formulas with the error:

- Pivot Tables
- VBA Code (none are event based... regular subs that need to be manually started only)
- Other Datatables

I have tested on the the following Systems:

- Excel 2010 (32bit) and Windows XP
- Excel 2010 (64bit) and Windows 7

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Do you have your DB data manually or automatically updated?

Comment: Hi Peter: The DB is updated manually... in fact there are no external references in the workbook.

Comment: Then how you get your DB data in Excel if you have NO external connections???

Comment: The name of the reference might be misleading... `tblDB` is simply the name that I gave to the Datatable. It is not a reference to an external database... i could also call it `MyTableInExcel`... does that help to clear it up?

Comment: @excelnove it definitely does) sorry for the confusion

Comment: Looks to me like the first reference in tblDB is no longer available - the range doesn't exist (a column or row has probably been deleted). Can you confirm what the `tblDB #REF!` reference is meant to point to? Replacing #REF! with the correct range name will make the #NAME error go away.

Comment: @MattCrum: That is what I also thought. However, as I explained above, I fixed the reference, saved and closed the workbook, and then reopened it two minutes later only to see the same error appear. Furthermore, no Columns or Column Names were changed.